# Retrieving the COM class factory for component failed due to the following error: 80040154. '

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook

I have an Asp.net Website which uses outlook dll.
I am using the below code

```
    Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application
    Dim mailitem As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)
    mailitem.To = legRev
    mailitem.CC = cc
    mailitem.Subject = Subject
    mailitem.HTMLBody = "Hi, <br/>"
    mailitem.HTMLBody += "<br/> The Deal - " + ClientName + ", has been Assigned to you for Legal Review. <br/><br/>"
    mailitem.HTMLBody += "Expected Signature Date : " + SignDate + " <br/>"
    mailitem.HTMLBody += "Customer Funding Date   : " + FundingDate + " <br/>"
    mailitem.HTMLBody += "Financed Amount   : " + sFinancedAmount + " <br/><br/>"
    mailitem.HTMLBody += "Please, click here to provide your final approval. <br/><br/>"
    If innerCC.Length = 0 Then
        mailitem.HTMLBody += "<a href=mailto:" + innerTo + "?Subject=" + innerSubject + ">" + PathName + "</a>"
    Else
        mailitem.HTMLBody += "<a href=mailto:" + innerTo + "?CC=" + innerCC + "&Subject=" + innerSubject + ">" + PathName + "</a>"
    End If

    mailitem.Display(False)
```

When I run the code I am getting an error like , 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154. '.

I dont have outlook installed. But I have copied the interop.outlook dll to my GAC.

Please help

Comment: Your running as x86 with x86 Outlook? Do you *really* need to use Outlook from Asp.net? Pain awaits and there are better ways to send email

Comment: That is what the "I dont have outlook installed" error message looks like.

Comment: @Alex - I am not supposed to use Mailmessage, smtp. Please suggest me some alternative solution. My requirement is, On clicking a button Outlook mail item should open which should have link in body. On clicking that link another mail item should open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, no Office app (including Outlook) should be used in a service, such as IIS.
Secondly, interop.outlook dll is nothing but a glorified header file. You actually need to have Outlook installed to be able to use it.

Comment: Is there any alternative solutions except MailMessage, smtp to do this functionality? My requirement is, On clicking a button Outlook mail item should open which should have link in body. On clicking that link another mail item should open.

Comment: Then your code must run on the client side in the browser. Why not use a mailto link and specify body as one of the parameters?

Comment: To write the code in client side also we need to add the outlook reference to my bin right. I should not use that dll. It will create a problem when I deploy the code to the server. Because my server does not has outlook installed.